# How to create axes outside of graph plane

Tags: jsxgraph

I'd like to create a graph where the x and y axis are to the bottom and left of the graph respectively. I guess this would mean creating the axes outside of the bounding box?

So I get something like this:

`10 - | 
    9 - |
    8 - |
    7 - |
    6 - |   graph/grid here ...
    5 - |
    4 - |
    3 - |
    2 - |
    1 - |
    0 - ———————————————————————————————
        |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10`

I've been trying with setting the offset of the axis labels, but they eventually get clipped by the containing svg.

It's not clear to me how to configure this.

Here's a pen I've been trying with: https://codepen.io/edeustace/pen/vZyXJE

Answer (score 0):

You can add the offset for the labels manually into the board creation like this:

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('regular', {
    boundingbox: [-1, 11, 11, -1],
    axis: true,
    grid: true,
    zoom: false,
    showNavigation:false,
});
```

Which results in:

[image: jsxgraph board]

Online: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyLzKx